# Must a std::set store the tree's root?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, binary-tree, stdset

A tree will be used as the internal data structure of `std::set`. The `begin` (and `cbegin`) methods of `std::set` have constant complexity, so `std::set` must have a private data member node pointer to the first element of the set; updated by calls which modify the set.

*Must* `std::set` *also* store a pointer to the root? For `insert` say, one O(log(n)) operation could find the root, and another could apply the traditional algorithm afterwards. There would be overheads, but it would still have the required complexity; and each `std::set` object would be one pointer smaller in size.

Comment: If each node has a parent pointer, which, presumably it does - otherwise it's hard to see how one could navigate the tree starting from `begin` - then the root could be discovered as needed by iterating the tree until a node with no parent is found (the root). But this would cause inserts and deletes to be potentially quite slow.

Comment: And you would agree that the complexity then remains O(log(n))?

Comment: I believe that's correct.